# Having issue with file input in my C++ program

Tags: c++, file, input, file-io

My code compiles but for some reason there is one error that comes up:

```
Error:Multiple markers at this line - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void open(const char *, enum std::_Ios_Openmode) ' - no 
matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream::open(std::__cxx11::string&)'
```

I cannot seem to figure out why this error is thrown.

Here's my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
     int array_for_numbs[10];
     int numbers[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     int counttarr[9]={0};
      ifstream fileinpt;
       int num, dgt;
        string txtfile;
        cout<<"enter the test file:";
         cin >> txtfile;
         fileinpt.open(txtfile);// this line is where the error pops up :(
          int i=0;
 while (!fileinpt.eof())
 {
      fileinpt >> array_for_numbs[i];
      i=i+1;
 }
fileinpt.close();
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
      num=array_for_numbs[i];
      do
      {
          dgt=num%10;
          num=num/10;
      }while(num>0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
          if(dgt==numbers[i])
          {
               counttarr[i]=counttarr[i]+1;
          }
      }
  }
    cout<<"Digit \t"<< "Count \t"<<"Frequency "<<endl;
   for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
 {
      float frq=(float)counttarr[i]/(float)100;
      cout<<(i+1)<<"\t"<< counttarr[i]<<"\t" <<frq<<endl;
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

"open" function filename argument has char* datatype, however, you are trying to pass std::string type path. Open function is a C function which is not aware of std::string type.

You have to cast/convert std::string to char*

Use;

```
fileinpt.open(txtfile.c_str());
```